# In a layout, how can I increase the padding around Switch text, so the text fits within the Switch?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In Android Studio, I have created a Switch. The Switch has the `textOff` and `textOn` attributes set, so when the Switch is checked, it looks like this:
[image: the Switch checked]

As you can see, **the text is too large for the Switch.** I never had this problem when using a Holo Switch, but I believe this is the Material design style that is used nowadays. Either way, I need to use this switch style (or one that looks like it) for this project.

Here is the code for the Switch, which is contained within a vertical `LinearLayout`, as the only item on its row:

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchIncludeOperator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:showText="true"
        android:textOff="@string/no"
        android:textOn="@string/yes" />
```

I want to enlarge the switch so that it will fit the containing text.

I have tried setting the `android:thumbTextPadding` property, which was my best guess. However, it doesn't do what I want. For example, a `thumbTextPadding` of `10dp` looks like this: [image: with thumbTextPadding]

I have tried other settings, like `switchPadding` and `drawablePadding`, but I havent found a solution that works yet. I even tried setting the scale properties to `2` (both with and without decreasing the text size): [image: scaled]

**How can I expand the circle to fit the text?**

*I'd like to avoid manually creating a bunch of custom drawables, if possible.*

**EDIT:**

Increasing the `textSize` property doesn't actually change the text size. It does seem to increase the empty area around the switch:

With `textSize` at `2sp`:

[image: 2sp textSize]

With `textSize` at `30sp`:

[image: 30sp textSize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to make it without any drawables - you can make your own style like:

```
 <style name="SwitchTextAppearence">
    <item name="android:textSize">5sp</item>
</style>
```

Which will have any parameters you want to aply to your switch text, and then use it by your switch using:

```
android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearence"
```

You can also do it in code using that:

```
switch.setSwitchTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.SwitchTextAppearence);
```

If you want to expand the circle with text you can easily use:

```
android:scaleX="@dimen/switchSize"
android:scaleY="@dimen/switchSize"
```

But that will expand all elements of your switch including text.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the `textSize` property does not resolve the issue. It *does* result in some unexpected behavior: it increases the empty space around the switch. See my edit on the question for example images.

Comment: @DavidGay Are you sure about adding `textSize` attribute with your own style and using `android:switchTextAppearance` to change your text style, not only size.  Because changing `textSize` attribute I got the same effect, as you get, but changing style leads to solution of your problem, as I saw. Are you sure about using style, not attribute?

Comment: Your solution works. When I wrote that comment, I had tried (1) changing `textSize` directly, and, (2) creating a style in the manner you described, but _applying the style to `style` instead of `switchTextAppearance`_. I had to make sure I applied the style to the `switchTextAppearance` property. I wonder why you have to change the `textSize` in that way (with a style and not directly). Seems a bit roundabout.

Comment: @DavidGay I'm glad I've helped :)